# Correlated subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery, ingres

Could someone help me with Correlated subquery  in  `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause using below example of exercise, cause I am not sure how to write this subquery and how would this work in INGRES database.

Let's say we have pension plan members who set aside funds to save for retirement.

Money is being converted into units which are on member's registers in database

We have 2 tables:

Table A - registers status

```
Columns:
    subfund_id 
    units_blocked 
    register_number 
    subfund_flag -  this means wheather the register_number 
                        belongs to subfund - 0 means no, 1 means yes
```

Table B -  funds and subfunds

```
columns
    subfund_id
    subfund_full_name
```

**Lets say we want to display all subfund_id and subfund_full_name for which there is at least one registry
with a balance of blocked units greater than zero**

My idea is:

```
    SELECT
    subfund_id, subfund_full_name
FROM
    Table B as t02
WHERE subfund_flag = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM Table A as t01
                WHERE t01.subfund_id = t02.subfund_id
                AND  units_blocked = 0)

GROUP BY
    subfund_id, subfund_full_name
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT register_number) >= 1
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Try: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...... and units_blocked >0 )`   (Leave out the NOT, and find "at least one registry with a balance of blocked units greater than zero" )

Comment: Hmm ok and with `NOT` the code in this form wont work ? Or maybe will show other results

Comment: The code in your question just selects lines that do NOT have a (1 or more)  `units_blocked=0`